# Join elements in 2D array with similar values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

So my array is as follows:

```
array = [ [5, type1, quantity1, price1] , 
      [2, type2, quantity2, price2] ,
      [2, type1, quantity3, price1]
    ]
```

The above values are not constant and they can vary. Whats important is that they match and they add together creating 1 element.

So, since `array[0]` and `array[2]` have the same type and price (`array[n][1] and array[n][3]`), the resulting array should look like:

```
[ [7, type1, quantity1+quantity3, price1], 
  [2, type2, quantity2, price2]
]
```

The array has an N length. I'm trying to find the optimal algorithm to do this but I can't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you attach sample input?

Comment: @Derek.W its at the beginning of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a combined key and add value and quantity.

```js
const
    array = [[5, 'type1', 10, 'price1'], [2, 'type2', 11, 'price2'], [2, 'type1', 12, 'price1']],
    grouped = Object.values(array.reduce((r, [value, type, quantity, price]) => {
        const key = [type, price].join('|');
        if (r[key]) {
            r[key][0] += value;
            r[key][2] += quantity;
        } else r[key] = [value, type, quantity, price];
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't tried this but I don't know if it would work. The values "type and price" are not constant, its just a place holder I put. It can be a variety of values. So you are putting const key with type and price, when it should be whatever value is in that position. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you I got it working. Do you mind explaining the part where you do .[type, price].join('|') ?

Comment: this is to get a joint key of the values of `type` and `price` joined with a pipe `'|'`.